# I spent a couple of votes. Why am I not showing up in the "voters" page?

Tags: support, voting, user-interface

In the [Users](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users) section there's a page that shows the [top voters for the week](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week).

I asked a question and voted on the best answers I got, but I'm not showing up on the voters page.

Why is that? Is this a bug or just a cache lag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like this is by design.

If you go to the very last page of all-time voters on the site, you'll see that anyone with less than 11 votes isn't showing up.

**You need to vote some more. *And then some***.

Simple as that! ;)

---

Voting generates *reputation* on the site.

For the beta site CR is, ***voting is like breathing*. If we stop voting, the site dies**.

Don't just upvote answers to *your* question.

*Spend more votes*. It's important. You get to vote up to 40 times *every day*. Also you get to earn [*civic-duty*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/civic-duty) and [*electorate*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/electorate) badges for voting, too.